# Extremely low connection to my projects from WAN

Tags: wifi, ethernet, connection

I own a Raspberry 3 b+ connected by WiFi. I'm storing my Codeigniter (php) projects there, but it takes a very long time to load any of these projects from WAN.

I'm using NO-IP to access the raspberry from the internet and I'm using an SSL certificate from **Let's Encrypt**. I have 600mbps of connection for upload and download.

Connecting to my projects via LAN is super fast, but when trying to connect to them via WAN is very slow.

There's something I don't understand, I'm using PhpMyAdmin to connect to MySQL, and PhpMyAdmin works like a charm from WAN, there's practically no delay and it works really fast.

Is there any setting I'm missing to solve this speed problem with my projects?

Comment: Your DNS provider and your certificate provider are not related to the transfer speed. How exactly do you access the PI via WAN? What kind of protocol?

Comment: @RalfFriedl Via HTTPS. FTP connections go fast.

Comment: If you don't use HTTPS on the LAN, then maybe the PI is just not fast enough to do the encryption at high speed.

Comment: @RalfFriedl but how is that possible if I'm accessing phpmyadmin from WAN using HTTPS? I mean I don't get it, I can't understand what the problem is